# Number check failing/getting ignored. Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a strike system that allows up to 3 strikes, so, when I try to check if the `strikeNumber` is between 1 and 3, it ignores the `if` statement, I'm not sure why, but I've tried multiple ways to fix it, and it still seems to fail.

Here is the `if` statement that is getting ignored:

```js
           let strikeNumber = args[2] //(Args 0 is the command it self, Args 1 is the user, Args 2 is the `Strikenumber`, and Args 3 is the reason.)

            if (!strikeNumber) {
                return message.reply("Please state the number of the strike. (Example: 1, 2, 3)")
            } if (!strikeNumber > 0 && !strikeNumber < 4) {
                return message.reply("Strike number must be from 1 to 3.")
            }
```

Not all the code is here, and there is no error, it just ignores the `if` statement.

Comment: Keep in mind the value 0 is falsey therefor `!strikeNumber` will never be true if your values are between 1-3. Furthermore the not operator will convert the value it's being applied on to a boolean, `!strikeNumber > 0` evaluates to `true/false > 0`.

Comment: I'm brain dead, do you mind explaining what I could do to change that?
I tired `!strikeNumber == 1 || !strikeNumber == 2 || !strikeNumber == 3` and it still ignored it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the second condition with this, it checks if the number is below zero `or` above 4

```
if ( num < 0 || num > 4 )
```

Comment: Didn't work, still ignores it and goes to "You must state a reason!".

Comment: By the way, I had it as "?strike [Userid] 0"

Comment: When you provide 0, !strikeNumber returns true and the first condition block executes

Comment: Do I make a separate if statement to block 0?

Comment: When you gave the arguments, you did not provide the reason, and the program resulted in "You must state a reason!". try providing all arguments first.

Comment: Ah, I see, but why would it need all the arguments to be send first?

Comment: Found a way around it by making it all a "Else if" chain, it made it HAVE to go thru the strike number first.
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you are using 2 if statements instead of an if else? Does this accomplish your goal?

```
if (!strikeNumber) {
    return message.reply("Please state the number of the strike. (Example: 1, 2, 3)")
} else {

    if (x === 1 || x === 2 || x === 3) {
        return message.reply("Strike number is 1, 2 or 3")
    } else {
        return message.reply("Strike number must be from 1 to 3.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Already tried it, didn't seem to work, however, I just found a good answer, thanks for helping!